# Another interpretation of Motzkin paths

Tags: combinatorics

We have

**Number of Motzkin $\bf{n}$-paths**: paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,0)$ in an $n\times n$ grid using only steps $U = (1,1)$, $F = (1,0)$ and $D = (1,-1)$.

https://oeis.org/, they said that number of Motzkin $n$-paths will be equal to number of sequences of length $n-1$ consisting of positive integers such that the first and last elements are $1$ or $2$ and the absolute difference between any $2$ consecutive elements is $0$ or $1$.

But I don't know how to prove it (I intend to construct a bijection but I don't know how to do).

Could you please help me explain why they are similar?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under the first interpretation of the Motzkin numbers, given a path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,0)$, consider the sequence of $y$-coordinates of the path. The result is a sequence of length $n+1$, starting with $0$ and ending with $0$, such that the absolute difference between adjacent points is zero or one. If you trim the zeroes at the beginning and end, and then add one to each entry to make all the entries positive integers, then this sequence is a sequence of length $n-1$, consisting of positive integers, starting and ending with $1$ or $2$. This is the bijection you seek.

Comment: many thank. Wish you a happy new year